# Can someone help me in construction of a one time unconditionally secure MAC scheme?

Tags: encryption

[image: Question states what is one time MAc security is and asks to define a scheme the satisfies the one time secure MAC]

The MAC scheme should not be using any primitives like PRG, PRF or PRP. Ok what could be possible solution if we ignore the statement "

Comment: Perhaps a Carter-Wegman Message Authentication Code using arithmetic in a binary field? But does this match the vague "not use any arithmetic operations" ?

Comment: That "not use any arithmetic operations" is either *really hard* or meaningless. Everything computers do other than a load or a store is an arithmetic operation ("logical" operations are just arithmetic operations in the Boolean algebra) or nothing is (arithmetic operations are just applications of Boolean circuits). You could write a Carter-Wegman MAC algorithm with nothing but the multi-input boolean functions available in FPGA LUTs, after all, and it could be made quite efficient. But I doubt that's what the assignment wants.

Comment: Although the question is interesting I've closed it until the last sentence is cleared up, as I don't think it is possible to answer this without clarification. Please hit [edit] and clarify!

Comment: We have to guess what the modified question wants to be ignored. Another reason to keep the question closed is that it is a straight dump of homework, without showing what was attempted, or even retyping it LaTex. The simplest that could be an answer goes: work in a binary field $(F_{2^n},+,\cdot)$, and use a "one-time Message Authentication Code" $m\mapsto a\cdot m+b$ with key $(a,b)$ in $\left(\{0,1\}^n\right)^2$. If the large key and MAC are an issue (e.g. contradict definitions given that require $n$ to grow faster than the MAC size), move to a "Carter-Wegman Message Authentication Code".

Comment: If we make a generous interpretation of "no arithmetic operations" to mean the tag itself does not involve any "computation" during signing, then one solution is to get creative with the key space.